# How to extend previous day sessions high low in TradingView Pinscript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Following is a working code which marks the high and low of defined sessions.

How to extend previous day sessions like for example if I input 0 it should extend today's session, if I input 1 it should  extends previous day session, 2 should extends 2 day before session?

Currently it draws high and low without extending the past sessions. My intention is to see previous day session lines today.

Expectation:
[image: White lines are expected result by extending sessions by day. Blue lines are already plotted lines.]

Code:

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='Session High & Low', shorttitle='HL', overlay=true)

// Menu
g_s_1 = 'Session 1'
i_ses_1_show = input.bool(defval=true, title='4h', inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_time = input.session(defval='1130-1530:1234567', title='', inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_h_col = input.color(defval=#00FFFF, title='', inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_l_col = input.color(defval=#00FFFF, title='', inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_style = input.string(defval='_____', title='', options=['_____', '.......', '-------'], inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_wid = input(defval=1, title='', inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_ext = input.string(defval='none', title='', options=['none', 'right', 'left', 'both'], inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_past = input.bool(defval=false, title='Past', inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_show_label = input.bool(defval=true, title='Label', inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)
i_ses_1_label_size = input.string(defval='small', title='', options=['tiny','small','normal','large','huge'], inline='s_1_1', group=g_s_1)

g_s_2 = 'Session 2'
i_ses_2_show = input.bool(defval=true, title='1hr', inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_time = input.session(defval='1430-1530:1234567', title='', inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_h_col = input.color(defval=#00FFFF, title='', inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_l_col = input.color(defval=#00FFFF, title='', inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_style = input.string(defval='_____', title='', options=['_____', '.......', '-------'], inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_wid = input(defval=1, title='', inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_ext = input.string(defval='none', title='', options=['none', 'right', 'left', 'both'], inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_past = input.bool(defval=false, title='Past', inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_show_label = input.bool(defval=true, title='Label', inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)
i_ses_2_label_size = input.string(defval='small', title='', options=['tiny','small','normal','large','huge'], inline='s_2_2', group=g_s_2)

g_s_3 = 'Session 3'
i_ses_3_show = input.bool(defval=true, title='1hr', inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_time = input.session(defval='0915-1015:1234567', title='', inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_h_col = input.color(defval=#00FFFF, title='', inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_l_col = input.color(defval=#00FFFF, title='', inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_style = input.string(defval='_____', title='', options=['_____', '.......', '-------'], inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_wid = input(defval=1, title='', inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_ext = input.string(defval='none', title='', options=['none', 'right', 'left', 'both'], inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_past = input.bool(defval=false, title='Past', inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_show_label = input.bool(defval=true, title='Label', inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)
i_ses_3_label_size = input.string(defval='small', title='', options=['tiny','small','normal','large','huge'], inline='s_3_3', group=g_s_3)

def_line_style(selection) =>
    ret = selection == '.......' ? line.style_dotted : selection == '-------' ? line.style_dashed : line.style_solid

def_line_extend(selection) =>
    ret = selection == 'right' ? extend.right : selection == 'left' ? extend.left : selection == 'both' ? extend.both : extend.none

def_label_size(selection) =>
    ret = selection == 'tiny' ? size.tiny : selection == 'small' ? size.small : selection == 'normal' ? size.normal : selection == 'large' ? size.large : size.huge

def_sesion_high_low(session_time, h_color, l_color, style, width, extend, past, show_label, label_size)=>
    sess_time_allowed = not na(time(timeframe.period, session_time))
    sess_new = sess_time_allowed and not sess_time_allowed[1]

    var float sess_high = na
    sess_high := sess_time_allowed and not sess_time_allowed[1] ? high : sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] ? high > sess_high ? high : sess_high : sess_high
    var float sess_low = na
    sess_low := sess_time_allowed and not sess_time_allowed[1] ? low : sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] ? low < sess_low ? low : sess_low : sess_low
    var int sess_x = na
    sess_x := sess_new ? time : sess_x

    var int sess_h_line_x1 = na
    var int sess_h_line_x2 = na
    var float sess_h_line_y1 = na
    var float sess_h_line_y2 = na

    var int sess_l_line_x1 = na
    var int sess_l_line_x2 = na
    var float sess_l_line_y1 = na
    var float sess_l_line_y2 = na

    var sess_h_line = line(na)
    var sess_h_prev_line = line(na)
    var sess_l_line = line(na)
    var sess_l_prev_line = line(na)

    var label sess_h_label = label(na)
    var label sess_l_label = label(na)

    var int sess_counter = 0
    var float sess_sum = na

    // Previous Sessions
    if sess_new
        sess_counter := 1
        sess_sum := close
        sess_h_prev_line := line.new(x1=sess_h_line_x1, y1=sess_h_line_y1, x2=sess_h_line_x2, y2=sess_h_line_y2, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=h_color, width=width, style=def_line_style(style))//, extend=def_line_extend(extend))
        sess_l_prev_line := line.new(x1=sess_l_line_x1, y1=sess_l_line_y1, x2=sess_l_line_x2, y2=sess_l_line_y2, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=l_color, width=width, style=def_line_style(style))//, extend=def_line_extend(extend))
        sess_l_prev_line

    // Current Session
    if sess_time_allowed and not sess_new and timeframe.isintraday
        sess_counter += 1
        sess_sum += close
        line.delete(sess_h_line)
        line.delete(sess_l_line)
        label.delete(sess_h_label)
        label.delete(sess_l_label)
        sess_h_line := line.new(x1=sess_x, y1=sess_high, x2=time, y2=sess_high, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=h_color, width=width, style=def_line_style(style), extend=def_line_extend(extend))
        sess_l_line := line.new(x1=sess_x, y1=sess_low, x2=time, y2=sess_low, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=l_color, width=width, style=def_line_style(style), extend=def_line_extend(extend))
        sess_h_label := label.new(x=bar_index, y=sess_high, text='def_label_text(sess_high)', textcolor=h_color, size=def_label_size(label_size), textalign=text.align_left, color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_left)
        sess_l_label := label.new(x=bar_index, y=sess_low, text='def_label_text(sess_low)', textcolor=l_color, size=def_label_size(label_size), textalign=text.align_left, color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_left)
        sess_l_label

    // Set Previous Values
    if past and not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new
        sess_h_line_x1 := ta.valuewhen(not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new, line.get_x1(sess_h_line), 0)
        sess_h_line_x2 := ta.valuewhen(not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new, line.get_x2(sess_h_line), 0)
        sess_h_line_y1 := ta.valuewhen(not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new, line.get_y1(sess_h_line), 0)
        sess_h_line_y2 := ta.valuewhen(not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new, line.get_y2(sess_h_line), 0)

        sess_l_line_x1 := ta.valuewhen(not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new, line.get_x1(sess_l_line), 0)
        sess_l_line_x2 := ta.valuewhen(not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new, line.get_x2(sess_l_line), 0)
        sess_l_line_y1 := ta.valuewhen(not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new, line.get_y1(sess_l_line), 0)
        sess_l_line_y2 := ta.valuewhen(not sess_time_allowed and sess_time_allowed[1] and not sess_new, line.get_y2(sess_l_line), 0)

def_sesion_high_low(i_ses_1_time, i_ses_1_h_col, i_ses_1_l_col, i_ses_1_style, i_ses_1_wid, i_ses_1_ext, i_ses_1_past, i_ses_1_show_label, i_ses_1_label_size)
def_sesion_high_low(i_ses_2_time, i_ses_2_h_col, i_ses_2_l_col, i_ses_2_style, i_ses_2_wid, i_ses_2_ext, i_ses_2_past, i_ses_2_show_label, i_ses_2_label_size)
def_sesion_high_low(i_ses_3_time, i_ses_3_h_col, i_ses_3_l_col, i_ses_3_style, i_ses_3_wid, i_ses_3_ext, i_ses_3_past, i_ses_3_show_label, i_ses_3_label_size)
```

Comment: the solution would be to to use `line.set_extend(sess_h_prev_line, extend.right)` for example. but without a `input()` to define your wishes its not possible.